# Search in web with F#

Tags: types, f#, functional-programming

Hi i want to search all the functional lenguages that exist on a page, each programming lenguage is listed in a table, the page im using is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages#Paradigm_summaries

I will have the results in a two tuple and the code that im using to acomplish this is:

```
#r "/usr/lib/cli/fsharp/FSharp.Data.2.4.2/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
type Multiparadigm = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages#Paradigm_summaries">
let multi =
    [ for x in Multiparadigm.GetSample().Tables.``Lenguage overview``.Rows ->
        x.Type, x.``Functional`` ]
```

I saved it in a .fsx file and when i use Fsharpc in ubuntu the error i get is:

```
/Documents/Fsharp/testF#/getDataFPage.fsx(5,43): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Languaje overview' is not defined

/Documents/Fsharp/testF#/getDataFPage.fsx(6,9): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

/Documents/Fsharp/testF#/getDataFPage.fsx(6,17): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
```

I want to know what im doing wrong, cause in the interactive tool i get:

```
Referenced '/usr/lib/cli/fsharp/FSharp.Data.2.4.2/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)
```

Comment: Im using nuget to install FSharp.Data and already look for it to be sure the FSharp.Data.dll is in the right path

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo it's `Language` not `Lenguage` nor `Languaje`.

Also note that the property `Type` is not there.

So if you do those two small changes to your code it should work:

```
#r "/usr/lib/cli/fsharp/FSharp.Data.2.4.2/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
type Multiparadigm = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages#Paradigm_summaries">
let multi =
    [ for x in Multiparadigm.GetSample().Tables.``Language overview``.Rows ->
        x.Language,  x.``Func­tion­al`` ]
```

It gives you something like this:

```
type Multiparadigm = HtmlProvider<...>
val multi : (string * string) list =
  [("Ada[3][4][5][6][7]", "No"); ("ALF", "Yes");
   ("AmigaE[citation needed]", "No"); ("APL", "Yes");
   ("BETA[citation needed]", "Yes"); ("C++", "Yes"); ("C#", "Yes[a 5]");
...
```